# How to migrate from Ubuntu 19.04 to 20.10?

Tags: upgrade, 19.04, migration

I'm trying to migrate a Ubuntu 19.04 install to the last Ubuntu version.
The problem is the migration tool refuses to update to the next version:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
For upgrade information, please visit:
http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife

Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,336 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Fetched 1,338 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'focal.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager

Can not upgrade 

An upgrade from 'disco' to 'focal' is not supported with this tool.
```

How can I migrate instead of a fresh install where I would have to reconfigure everything?

Thanks in advance for your kind help

Comment: The unfortunate part is that there isn't an upgrade path from 19.04 to 20.10.  The path would have to go to 19.10 first, which is EOL as well and not upgradeable/installable.  It would have to be a clean install to 20.10.

Comment: I remember having to do something similar once. I think there is a way to trick the upgrader into thinking you are on a different version, but things can get very unstable after that. You could also do a reinstall where you preserve the /home/ directory, so you only have to reinstall programs, not reconfigure anything.

Comment: You can't skip release when upgrading. 19.04 went EOL in January.  You should upgrade *before* your system reaches EOL. Its successor 19.10 also went EOL in July. Unfortunately, this probably means you've waited far too long to upgrade your current system, so your only path is likely to install a supported release from scratch.  Don't ever let your OS go EOL because that means your support has lapsed.  If you don't want to upgrade every 6 months, stick with a LTS release like 18.04 or 20.04 - they are supported for 3-5 years. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: You should probably install 20.04 instead of 20.10 if you are not going to be prepared to upgrade again between April and June of 2021, and every 6 months after

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/) and [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Answer (score 1):

You missed the boat, sorry.

There is no tested upgrade path from 19.04 to 20.04 nor to 20.10.

The upgrade window for 19.04 to 19.10 closed in July 2020.

The supported, recommended, safe, easy way is to create a new 20.04 or 20.10 install USB and clean-install.

The unsupported, untested, blaze-your-own-trail way is to manually change your sources, then run a dist-upgrade. However, we don't provide support for it: If you run into problems, we will merely recommend a clean-install.

- 19.04 stopped receiving security patches in January 2020. That alone is reason enough to clean-reinstall.